# Moongose find function does not works with variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, mongodb

I need to search for documents with Moongose with dynamic variables through a GET request but moongose does not works with them

The following code I have so far

```
// nodejs code

let key = req.body.key;
let value = req.body.value;
let filter = {};
filter[key] = value;

let query = PRODUCTS.find( Object.keys(filter).length === 0 ? {}: filter, {_id: 0});
```

```
// moongose schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productOtherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productType: {type: String, required: true},
    branchOffice: {type: String, required: true},
    productDescription: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    purchasePrice: {type: Number, required: true},
    salePrice: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ProductOther', productOtherSchema, 'products');
```

If I hardcode the values into find function, it works perfectly, but this is not I need, for example:

```
// this hardcode code works perfectly

let query = PRODUCTS.find({ branchOffice: 'Office 1'}, {_id: 0});
```

Comment: Can you use ```PRODUCTS.find( key: value, {_id: 0})``` directly, instead of storing it to an object?

Comment: nop because in that way "key" literally mean "key" instead of the content of the variable

Comment: use it like this `PRODUCTS.find( [key]: value, {_id: 0})`

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: there is no error, simply it returns all the documents

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(filter)`?

Comment: filter contains the dictionary with the key and value correctly: filter: [object Object]

Comment: if `Object.keys(filter).length === 0` then surely filter object will be {}, so adding the ternary is useless. so as @RinkeshGolwala suggested use `PRODUCTS.find( [key]: value, {_id: 0})`

Comment: Thanks for your help here, actually all answers all good for me, the mistake that I did is with POSTMAN send double quotes and thus causing an empty search, I remove the double quotes and all works suddenly